# Can I use Apache Pivot instead of Swing?

Tags: java, swing, apache-pivot

I saw Apache Pivot, but this is meant for "installable Internet applications". What are IIA and can I use Apache Pivot instead of Swing because I like the UI of Pivot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195539/apache-pivot-1-4-vs-javafx-flex-silverlight-swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installable internet applications are "client-side applications that leverage the Internet but do not require a browser" ([source](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/apache-upgrades-installable-internet-apps-platform-921)).

For a "Swing vs. Pivot" discussion, refer to the [question pointed out in Chandran's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195539/apache-pivot-1-4-vs-javafx-flex-silverlight-swing).

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you encounter a situation with legacy Swing code, and you'd like to migrate that code base to Apache Pivot, they can coexist.  To see how, refer to [this example code](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=27833&highlight=apache%20pivot) on the World Wind Java forums.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Pivot for a very large (>200,000 lines of code) desktop application, and it works very well. The "Internet" part of Pivot's description was the original intention, but it has equally good desktop support (actually better now that applets are pretty much phased out).