# apache pivot - desktop application

Tags: java, swing, apache-pivot

I want to know about apache pivot.is it possible to develop desktop applications using apache pivot.which is better swing or apache pivot?please help me to choose one..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2195539/977676 which says it cannot be good for desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to develop desktop applications with Apache Pivot, version 2.0.2.

As to whether Swing is better than Pivot for desktop development, it would depend on your needs.  I've developed several desktop applications in Swing.

One thing to consider, is that Swing is not under active development by Oracle, while Pivot is under active development.  Pivot has more native components.

Swing makes it easier to separate data (model) from the GUI (view).

Comment: >"Swing makes it easier to separate data (model) from the GUI (view)."
How it does it?

Answer (score 0):

We've implemented a huge desktop application (> 200,000 lines of code) using Apache Pivot, and it also works as an applet.  For me a big advantage of Pivot vs. Swing is that Pivot allows defining your application (or pieces of it) using an XML declaration, which reduces code a lot.